# How to access directories and files of an intranet in Windows using Rebol?

Tags: file, rebol

How can I access directories and files of an intranet in Windows using Rebol? How can I read a file such as this? :

```
\\name\dir\sub-dir\file.ext
```

I have tried:

```
read %//name/dir/sub-dir/file.ext
```

but it does not work.

Comment: I don't know about REBOL, but what about prepending something like `file:///`?

Answer (score 1):

in your example, you map machines, but not the path to the actual file.

so it should be:

```
read %/machine-name/DISK/folder/path/[file.ext]
```

where [file.ext] is optional.

for example:

```
read %/mycomputer/C/Users/Default/Pictures/
```

but is the disk shared to begin with?  note that with Windows 7 the system disk is still shared by default, using the C$ "system" share.

```
read %/mycomputer/C$/
```

works on my machine, out of the box, without any manual sharing on my part.

Note about windows machine browsing/remote access... it is possible that shares on remote machines are not available until you've browsed them within windows first.  Browsing via the explorer creates some some sort of login certificate which is then used by all attempts at remote browsing by the current user.

Note that you cannot list the root shares of a machine in REBOL. So this *is* invalid:

```
read %/machine/
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this way when I confused about file! types:

```
print read to-rebol-file "\\name\dir\sub-dir\file.ext"
```

which works always.
So you can see the correct syntax is:

```
%/name/dir/sub-dir/file.ext
```

if you have spaces in folder names, try:

```
%"/name/dir/sub dir/file.ext"
```

should work as well.

And also try:

```
read file:/name/dir/sub-dir/
```

if you put file:///name/dir/ then it will try to search /name/dir/ under the current path.

Comment: If I try for example: read %"/mycomputer/Users Default/Pictures/" it gives me an error.

Comment: Same with file:/...   It would be nice if file:/// was a scheme that do not search the current path (!!?) but does the correct thing

Comment: well, actually it works, I just tried read %/10.10.1.3/test/ works as expected. "mycomputer" is a network computer? if not you have to give it with volume letter: read %"/c/Users Default/pictures/". in my examples "name" is also a network computer.